# JMeter "Content encoding Error" when using FireFox and HTTP(S) Test Script recorder

Tags: firefox, encoding, jmeter, brotli

I am trying to configure Mozilla Firefox for JMeter 5 and as I am setting up manual proxy in Firefox and same proxy number in JMeter.

I installed the special certificate. 
My Firefox is showing error as "Content encoding Error", when I open https://www.google.com website.

[image: Content Encoding Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Brotli Encoding not being supported by JMeter Test Script Recorder in versions <= 5.0.

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62842

The bug is now fixed in nightly build and in upcoming 5.1 version of JMeter.

To workaround, in Firefox, type about:config and input Content-Encoding:

[image: Accept-Encoding]

Then remove **br** from the algorithms accepted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't load test public applications unless you're a member of their QA team or have an explicit permission from the application owner. Most probably you will be at least stopped by [DDoS protection mechanisms](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS) and your IP will be simply blacklisted which may cause problems for your neighbours if you're behind an ISP [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).
2. Whenever JMeter fails to record something try out an alternative way - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) which is a convenient way of intercepting browser traffic without having to configure proxy servers and installing certificates.